# Annotation does not appear in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The annotation "test" displays if I run the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("Test", xy=(0.2, 0.2))
```

However, the exact same code will not display the annotation if I call `plt.plot()` instead of `plt.figure()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("Test", xy=(0.2, 0.2))
```

Why does the second code block not show the annotation?

Comment: I see the annotation with both code blocks when calling `plt.show()` at the end. Are you using an interactive environment?

Comment: `matplotlib.backends.backend` returns `'Qt4Agg'`.   `matplotlib.is_interactive()` returns `True`.  Adding `plt.show()` at the end still leaves the annotation as not displayed for me.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem with either `TkAgg` or `Qt4Agg`, version `1.2.1` on Linux but I get `matplotlib.is_interactive()==False` with the default setup. Perhaps it is something to do with interactive mode?

Comment: On my machine, simply calling figure() sets xlim and ylim to `[0,1]` in the first example with the text within the domain, while in the second example the annotated test is outside the xlim and ylim, that are set to `[-.06,.06]`. Is this your problem?

Comment: If I start the code with `plt.ioff()` to turn off interactive mode, the annotation still does not display.

Comment: What are your `xlim` and `ylim`? In both cases please

Comment: Thanks flebool, that was indeed the issue.

Comment: I'll post it as the answer then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, calling `figure()` sets `xlim` and `ylim` to `[0,1]` with the text within the domain, at `[.2,.2]`.

In the second example the annotated test is outside the xlim and ylim.  They are set automatically to `[-.06,.06]` (at least on my machine).

In the second example, simply invoke

```
ax.set_xlim(-.4,.4)
ax.set_xlim(-.4,.4)
```

and the annotation will appear in the figure.